# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'extractDB.Properties.Settings.MasterConnectionString.get'

Tags: c#

```
namespace extractDB
{
class ConsoleApp2
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string dog ="fancy";
        string shep = "shepherd";
        Add _add = new Add();
        _add.Ex(45, dog, shep);
    }
}
class Add
{
    public void Ex(int weight, string name, string breed)
    {

  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(extractDB.Properties.Settings.MasterConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            try
            {
  using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO format(@Weight,@Name,@breed)", con))
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Weight", weight));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name", name));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Breed", breed));
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("count not inserted");
            }

        }

      }

  }
}
```

I'm getting an error message because of "extractDB.Properties.Settings.MasterConnectionString."

I checked in the app.config and settings.settings files and that's the string app.config gives me. I even tried adding in

```
static void Ex(int weight, string name, string breed)
```

but it doesn't get rid of the error message.

So yeah kind of lost on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conventional way of using configuration files to store Database Connection Strings would be to use the `<connectionStrings>` element at the root of your web or app.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add 
        name="NorthwindConnectionString" 
        connectionString="Data Source=serverName;Initial 
        Catalog=Northwind;Persist Security Info=True;User 
        ID=userName;Password=password"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
      />
    </connectionStrings>
<configuration>
```

You can then use the following code to access the connection string:

```
string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NorthwindConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

..instead of what you have:

```
extractDB.Properties.Settings.MasterConnectionString
```

Comment: Ah ok I was following the example from http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlclient My final code end up to be: string connStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["extractDB.Properties.Settings.MasterConnectionString"].ConnectionString; 

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr))

Answer (score 1):

You should be storing this in the app.config, but looking at your code it appears that you might be missing:

Try this:

```
string conn = extractDB.Properties.Settings.Default.MasterConnectionString;
```

Comment: storing this in the app.config file? This is what I currently have in the app.config file: <connectionStrings>
        <addname="extractDB.Properties.Settings.MasterConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=ncb1XXXXXXX;Initial Catalog=NameExample;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=testrun;Password=examplepassword"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error exactly because of what the compiler says: Either your `extracDB` object is not instantiated, or your `extractDB.Properties.Settings.MasterConnectionString` is not static. Double check your code for `extractDB.Properties.Settings.MasterConnectionString`